# Problemas ao instalar jdk7 ou 8 no MAC OS 10.6.8 - Snow Leopard

Tags: java, sistema-operacional

Sou iniciante em java, e tenho um MACBook com MAC OS X 10.6.8 mais conhecido como Snow Leopard.

Estou tentando instalar o jdk e o Netbeans no mesmo e não consigo.

Ele me diz que preciso da versão 10.7 do MAC OS.

Já tentei todas as versões de jdk 8 e 7, sem sucesso.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o download do `jdk7-7uX-macosx-x64.dmg` na [parte de downloads do site da Oracle.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Use o [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) para abrir e instalar o `JDK 7 Update X.pkg` que está no arquivo que você baixou.

Resposta original no SOEN: [How to install java jdk 7 on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024322/1964435)